# Css stylesheet has the wrong path when using gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, browser-sync

I have been struggling for a while now and it is fairly frustrating to be honest.

The problem:

I created a gulpfile for my static website, and all i want to do is use browserSync, to compile sass into css and to minify the script and css files. Everything works fine, excluding one thing:

When I run "gulp" everything loads, besides de css file, which is located in "CSS/". Apparently the server thinks that the css file is ("CSS/style.css/") a folder actually.

Screenshot with the console error:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/embvW.png)

**the css file is located in "css/style.css"**

```
   "use strict";

let paths = {
    script: "js/*.js",
    minifiedScript: 'script.min.js',
    cssPath: "css/*.css",
    productionFolder: "production",
    sassPath: "scss/*.scss",
    htmlFiles: "*.html"
};

const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const del = require('del');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const cssMin = require('gulp-css');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const inject = require('gulp-inject');
const rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.sassPath)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('index', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('index.html');
  // It's not necessary to read the files (will speed up things), we're only after their paths: 
  var sources = gulp.src([paths.script,paths.cssPath], {read: false});

  return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});

gulp.task('cssMinify', function(){
  return gulp.src(paths.cssPath)
    .pipe(cssMin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.productionFolder + "/minified css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  // You can use multiple globbing patterns as you would with `gulp.src` 
  return del(['build']);
});

gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
  // Minify and copy the JS file
  return gulp.src(paths.script)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat(paths.minifiedScript))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.productionFolder + "/minified JS"));
});

gulp.task('jsMinify:watch', function() { gulp.watch(paths.script, ['scripts']) });
gulp.task('sass:watch', function() { gulp.watch(paths.sassPath, ['sass']) });
gulp.task('cssMinify:watch', function() { gulp.watch(paths.cssPath, ['cssMinify']) });
gulp.task('html:watch', function() { gulp.watch(paths.htmlFiles).on('change', browserSync.reload) });

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'index', 'cssMinify', 'clean', 'html:watch', 'jsMinify:watch', 'sass:watch', 'cssMinify:watch','browserSync', 'scripts']); // DEVELOPMENT
```

Comment: What happens if you change baseDir from `"./"` to `""` ?? Also, in my gulpfile, for gulp.dest, they are not prefixed with `./`, so `gulp.dest('css')` instead of `gulp.dest('./css')`.

Comment: What is your css link in your html?

Comment: Also, could your problem be the order in which the tasks are run?  Because they are run in parallel not necessarily in the order you have them listed in the default task.